# Running the hello world OpenCL example on mac os x 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: opencl, osx-mavericks

I am trying to run the example that apple has posted in his developer library:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/ExampleHelloWorld/Example_HelloWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH112-SW2

I could not compile the example from the command line, until I read this thread:

[How to set up Xcode to run OpenCL code, and how to verify the kernels before building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046035/how-to-set-up-xcode-to-run-opencl-code-and-how-to-verify-the-kernels-before-bui)

which I found very useful and helpful. But I am still having problem when I try to run it. It gives me the following output:

```
Created a dispatch queue using the ATI Radeon HD 6750M
Abort trap: 6
```

Do I have to run the executable with a specific flag? It is related to my GPU? By the way, I am using a MacBookPro from early 2011 on Mac OSX 10.9.1 Mavericks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac computers: OpenCL and OpenGL support in OS X Mavericks see here
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5942

Answer (score 4):

ATI Radeon HD 6750M is supported. May be you should try this sample code

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenCL_Hello_World_Example/Introduction/Intro.html

For command line compile:

```
xcrun clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -framework OpenCL hello.c -o hello
```

Or you can refer to this to have a list of supported OpenCL devices on your machine
[How can i test for OpenCL compability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892955/how-can-i-test-for-opencl-compability)

Comment: Thank you. I will try if this compiles.

Comment: I found that I don't need to specify `-isysroot`. It compiles, links, and runs fine without it.